# C++ Vector subtraction

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, subtraction

I've been trying to make my vector calculator subtract. It was doing it fine with vectors that store the same amount of numbers, for example: `(+) 503 - (-) 305`. It would give me a good result on this kind of cases.

But when I tried subtracting different size vectors the problems appeared. I tried to solve the problem by making different filters to make the program act how I want it. But now, instead of subtracting all it does is add.

This is my setup:

```
const int MAX = 102;

typedef int vector[MAX];
```

A(0): Puts all the values of a vector at 0. For example:

Before using it:

```
[0][3][5][0][5]
```

Where the first 0 means it is a positive number, if it was [1] it would mean its negative, that [3] means that there are 3 numbers stored in the vector.

After using A0:

```
[0][1][0][0][0][0][0]...[0]
```

ES_MAJOR_VECTOR checks if vector Z > X. On that case returns true, else it's going to return false.

SUMA_VEC basically adds Z to X and then assings the value to W.

```
void RESTA_VEC(vector Z, vector X, vector W) {

    int ZigualX(0), Xmes1(0), Xactual(0), ZmajorX(0), XmajorZ(0), contador(0);
    vector copia_Z, copia_X;

    A0(copia_Z);
    A0(copia_X);

    for (int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
    {
        copia_Z[k] = Z[k];
        copia_X[k] = X[k];
    }

    if (Z[0] == X[0])
    {
        if (Z[0] == 0)
        {
            for (int y = MAX; y >= 2; y--)
            {
                if (Z[y] < X[y])
                {//RESTA
                    Z[y] = Z[y] + 10;
                    W[y] = Z[y] - X[y];
                    X[y + 1] = X[y + 1] + 1;
                }

                if (Z[y] > X[y])
                {
                    W[y] = Z[y] - X[y];
                }

                if (Z[y] == X[y])
                {
                    W[y] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Z[0] == 1)
        {
            SUMA_VEC(Z, X, W);
        }
    }
    
    if (Z[0] != X[0])
    {
        if (ES_MAJOR_VECTOR(Z, X) == true)
        {
            for (int y = MAX; y >= 2; y--)
            {
                if (Z[y] < X[y])
                {
                    Z[y] = Z[y] + 10;
                    W[y] = Z[y] - X[y];
                    X[y + 1] = X[y + 1] + 1;
                }

                if (Z[y] > X[y])
                {
                    W[y] = Z[y] - X[y];
                }

                if (Z[y] == X[y])
                {
                    W[y] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int y = MAX; y >= 2; y--)
            {
                if (X[y] < Z[y])
                {
                    X[y] = X[y] + 10;
                    W[y] = X[y] - Z[y];
                    Z[y + 1] = Z[y + 1] + 1;
                }

                if (X[y] > Z[y])
                {
                    W[y] = X[y] - Z[y];
                }

                if (X[y] == Z[y])
                {
                    W[y] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < MAX; h++)
    {
        Z[h] = copia_Z[h];
        X[h] = copia_X[h];
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? I've thought that I need to check: If they are positive or negative, if they're both positive I have to execute a subtraction, if they're negative I have to add Z to X and assign it to W.

If the vectors are different (Meaning one is positive and the another one is negative) I have to check which one is bigger, do the subtraction and then assign either 0 or 1 depending on the bigger vector of the two used earlier.

For example:

```
+5050
-305

W[0] = +

-5050
+305

W[0] = -
```

Comment: Do all four cases fail? i.e. `(+X) - (+Z)`, `(+X) - (-Z)`, `(-X) - (+Z)`, `(-X) - (-Z)`?

Comment: @NickReed I've fixed some of them, now (+X) - (+Z), (-X) - (-Z) works perfectly if the two vectors have the same size. Otherwise, it will give me wrong values.

Comment: @NickReed (+X) - (-Z) returns random values as if it was never given a value. And (-X) - (+Z) adds them. For example: (-505) - (+305) = 800

Comment: Remark: In real-life C++ code you should use std::array instead of C-style array. // If you aren't required to represent the internal data structure like this, it would be easier to represent the values in ten's complement notation.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you, i'd do it but my teacher wants it that way so I can't change it freely. I neither can use the vector library, can't store numbers < 0 and > 9 in one single cell

Comment: Re "can't store numbers <0 and>9 in one single cell"->Do you really know what's ten's complement notation?

Comment: Otherwise, you can still do typical [rubber-duck debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) yourself...

Comment: @user202729 After reading your question and googling it. No, I didn't know it.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you, it was a good read. I'll make better and actual questions from now on.

Comment: This one is not particularly bad (at least it has a [example]! or at least it looks like that) but it's pretty clear that most people are not willing to debug other people's code.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! I'll do better next time. Yeah I've noticed it. Totally understandable to be honest. I'd upvote you but I can't find the button :C

Comment: Looking at it again, the code included in the question is not complete (it doesn't provide the definitions of the other functions that the code calls) -- but in this case the core problem is just the subtraction loop. You should determine where exactly the bug is, then post only that part of the code as a [example] ([this is a reduced example with unnecessary parts removed](https://0x0.st/-suY.cpp)), with expected/actual output/what you think your code is doing -- at least make the code in the post complete (verifiable) so I can post an answer.

Comment: @user202729 I'm so sorry for my late reply. Thank you very much! I really apreciate it, I ended up finding a solution. I'll post it now hoping it helps someone in the future.

Comment: @user202729 And that solution is nearly the same as the one you showed me, at the beginning I didn't want to alter the value of the two original vectors so I was avoiding making direct alterations on them. So I ended up making back ups before executing any operation on them.

Comment: Wait... don't edit the question to add the answer. That's not how the site works. Post it as an answer instead. And if you have a new question, post a new question (remember to include a [example], as usual).

Comment: @user202729 Okay! I will

Answer (score 0):

After getting helped by a very kind user I could get to this conclusion:

```
void RESTA_ABS(vector Z, vector X, vector W) {

    int error(0);

    A0(W);
        
    if (ES_MAJOR_VECTOR(Z,X))
    {
        for (int i = MAX-1; i >= 2; i--)
        {
            if (Z[i] < X[i]) {

                Z[i] = Z[i] + 10;
                W[i] = Z[i] - X[i];
                X[i - 1] = X[i - 1] + 1;
            }           
            else
            {
                W[i] = Z[i] - X[i];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR - VECTOR 2 > VECTOR 1" << endl;
    }
}
```

This module doesn't mind about the vector being positive or negative. It just does the subtraction.

So, to solve this, I used another module:

void RESTA_VEC(vector Z, vector X, vector W) {

```
if (X[0] == 0)
{
    X[0] = 1;
}
else
{
    X[0] = 0;
}

RESTA_ABS(Z, X, W);

if (ES_MAJOR_VECTOR(Z, X) == true)
    {
        W[0] = Z[0];
    }
    else
    {
        W[0] = X[0];
    }
```

}

This one changes the number's sign of the second vector, making it negative if its positive, and positive if its negative. (This is determined by having a 0 or a 1 on the first vector position).

And then finally, what it does is to check the sign of the greater vector and assign it to the output vector W.

The only part left is checking which of the two vectors is greaters, because as I was testing it, on some cases, it would give me a wrong answer.

For example:

```
[+][9][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]
[+][9][1][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
```

Would give:

```
[+][8][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

But it doesn't make the opperation cause it thinks that the second vector is greater.

Translation: Is Z greater than X?

```
bool ES_MAJOR_VECTOR_SIGNE(vector Z, vector X) {

    int END(0), UP(2);

    return false;

    if (Z[1] > X[1])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        while (END != 1)
        {
            if (Z[UP] > X[UP])
            {
                return true;
                END = 1;
            }

            UP++;
        }
    }
}
```